# How to use Net::HTTP's `get_print` method

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'm trying to create and initialize an instance of `Net::HTTP` as HTTPClient. When I get to the get_print method, though, it is telling me that it doesn't exist. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
require 'Net/HTTP'

print "Enter address for HTTP request: "
URL = gets.chomp
puts ''

HTTPClient = Net::HTTP.new(URL, 80)

HTTPClient.get_print URI(URL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stored an instance of the class`Net::HTTP` in your `HTTPClient` constant. But `get_print` isn't an instance method of `Net::HTTP` ([see the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-get_print)),  it's a singleton method of the class object `Net::HTTP` itself. Therefore, you cannot call `get_print` on an instance.

Here's how you might use `get_print` appropriately:

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.get_print('www.google.com', '/')
```